# Effect sizes for pre-post control design but with uneuqal pre-post sample sizes?

Tags: effect-size, pre-post-comparison

I am trying to compute the effect sizes for the pre-post control design studies. Here is what I found in [Morris (2018)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428106291059?casa_token=vry48eoM180AAAAA:IDp4HG92XbZJlxGEIkAT9QPxEPpp3LYffPIj2qvDi67DTwbGqDEYNxv4C0seGjixcO4d9QZb7tZ11rM) and I quote
"For the PPC design, three effect size estimates have been recommended in the literature. Becker (1988)
suggested a measure of effect size using separate estimates of the pretest standard deviation in the treatment and
control groups (dppc1). Carlson and Schmidt (1999) used an effect size based on the pooled pretest standard
deviation (dppc2). Others (Dunlap et al., 1996; Taylor & White, 1992) have recommend pooling standard
deviations across both pretest and posttest scores (dppc3). "

I've decided to use dppc2 as suggested by Morris. The problem is I have unequal pre-post sample sizes (some participants just dropped out). For example:

1. grp1-sample-size-pre:70
2. grp1-sample-size-post:65
3. grp2-sample-size-pre:72
4. grp2-sample-size-post:64

What sample sizes do I use when calculating dppc2 and the variance?

From the functions below, I guess I should use sample sizes of the pre-groups, that is 70 and 72, because it is standardized by pooled pretest SD (correct me if I am wrong).

[image: from Morris (2008))]

But I am not sure about the variance, as it is not indicated in the function.

[image]